# How to remove repeated words from an excel

Tags: python-3.x

I need to remove common words that are there in each line of an excel using python. below is the example:

**sample.xlsx**

```
1 'abc 123 pqr row1'
2 'pqr abc1 123 row2'
3 '256 abcd row3 pqr'
```

in this the word `pqr` is repeated in all 3 rows, I need to find and remove such words.

**expected output:**

```
1 'abc 123 row1' 
2 'abc1 123 row2' 
3 '256 abcd row3'
```

Comment: Its a multi column excel, I've concatenated them into a single column

Comment: Add your expected output in the question

Comment: expected output is as below

1 'abc 123 row1'
2 'abc1 123 row2'
3 '256 abcd row3'

Answer (score 0):

It is easier if you use `pandas` library.

First find all `unique_words` in your column.
Then itertate over list of words and if `count > 1` replace that word.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("sample.xlsx")

unique_words = list(df['cola'].str.split(' ', expand=True).stack().unique())
# ['abc', '123', 'pqr', 'row1', 'abc1', 'row2', '256', 'abcd', 'row3']

for word in unique_words:
    pattern = r'\b{}\b'.format(word)
    if df['cola'].str.count(pattern).sum() > 1:
        df['cola'] = df['cola'].str.replace(word,"").str.replace("  "," ").str.strip()

print(df)
```

Output:

```
        cola                                                                                                                      
0       abc row1                                                                                                                      
1      abc1 row2                                                                                                                      
2  256 abcd row3
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I don't know which word is repeated. my excel is huge of 100K rows and need to find the word that repeats in al 100k rows and remove that. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @Ganesh please add all requirement at once in question so people can help easily. Thanks.

Comment: my apologizes, I should have mentioned in the first post itself. My requirement is to find the word that repeats in all rows of excel and remove that word, this is not limited to number of repeated words.